# Autobahn+twisted reconnecting

Tags: tcp, autobahn, reactor, reconnect, twisted.internet

I have a series of clients which need to be connected constantly to my server via `ws` protocol. For a number of different reasons, the connections occasionally drop. This is acceptable, but when it happens I'd like my clients to reconnect.

Currently my temporary workaround is to have a parent process launch the client and when it detects connection drop, terminate it (client never handles any critical data, there are no side effects to `sigkill`-ing it) and respawn a new client. While this does the job, I'd very much prefer to fix the actual problem.

This is roughly my client:

```
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketClientProtocol, WebSocketClientFactory
from twisted.internet import reactor
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep


class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self._kill = False

        self.factory = WebSocketClientFactory("ws://0.0.0.0")
        self.factory.openHandshakeTimeout = 60  # ensures handshake doesnt timeout due to technical limitations
        self.factory.protocol = self._protocol_factory()

        self._conn = reactor.connectTCP("0.0.0.0", 1234, self.factory)
        reactor.run()

    def _protocol_factory(self):
        class ClientProtocol(WebSocketClientProtocol):
            def onConnect(self, response):
                Thread(target=_self.mainloop, daemon=True).start()

            def onClose(self, was_clean, code, reason):
                _self.on_cleanup()

        _self = self
        return ClientProtocol

    def on_cleanup(self):
        self._kill = True
        sleep(30)
        # Wait for self.mainloop to finish. 
        # It is guaranteed to exit within 30 seconds of setting _kill flag
        self._kill = False
        self._conn = reactor.connectTCP("0.0.0.0", 1234, self.factory)

    def mainloop(self):
        while not self._kill:
            sleep(1)  # does some work
```

This code makes client work correctly until first connection drop at which point it attempts to reconnect. No exceptions are raised during the process, it appears that everything went correctly clientside, the `onConnect` is called and new `mainloop` starts, but the server never received that second handshake. Client seems to *think* it is connected, though.

What am I doing wrong? Why could this be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a twisted expert and can't really tell what you are doing wrong, but I'm currently working with Autobahn in a project and I solved the reconnection problems using the [ReconnectingClientFactory](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/17.5.0/api/twisted.internet.protocol.ReconnectingClientFactory.html). Maybe you want to check some [examples](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/tree/master/examples/twisted/websocket/reconnecting) of the use of ReconnectingClientFactory with Autobahn.